# Why don't I see my growth on the last year for each row on PowerBi?

Tags: powerbi

I have put on the dashboard of Power Bi a matrix with years on columns, district areas on rows and total actual revenue, absolute growth and percentage growth on the last year as values. Why don't I see the absolute growth for each district? I'm using also years as parameter

```
M-CY_Sales = CALCULATE(sum('Detail Sales Report'[Total Actual Revenue - Base]);filter('Detail Sales Report';'Detail Sales Report'[fiscal Year]=CurrentYear[CurrentYearValue]))

M-PY_Sales = CALCULATE(sum('Detail Sales Report'[Total Actual Revenue - Base]);filter('Detail Sales Report';'Detail Sales Report'[fiscal Year]=CurrentYear[CurrentYearValue]-1))

M-PY2_Sales = CALCULATE(sum('Detail Sales Report'[Total Actual Revenue - Base]);filter('Detail Sales Report';'Detail Sales Report'[fiscal Year]=CurrentYear[CurrentYearValue]-2))

M-PY_Growth = calculate([M-PY_Sales]-[M-PY2_Sales];'Detail Sales Report')

M-PY_Growth% = DIVIDE([M-PY_Growth];ABS([M-PY2_Sales]))

M-CY_Growth = [M-CY_Sales]-[M-PY_Sales]

M-CY_Growth% = DIVIDE([M-CY_Growth];ABS([M-PY_Sales]))
```

Comment: Are you seeing values for the measures M-PY_Sales and M-PY2_Sales? Is there a relationship in your data model between the tables 'Detail Sales Report' and 'CurrentYear'?

Comment: CurrentYear is a parameter that I'm using to set the year, I have also a timeintelligence table that is linked to Detail Sales Report. CurrentYear is not Linked. I see that M-CY Sales, M-PY Sales and M-PY2 Sales are the same of Total Actual Revenue in the matrix

Comment: The issue sounds like it's that the filter down to current year on those three measures isn't working. Growth is just a side effect of them all being the same. Next step to debug it might be trying to take out CurrentYear[CurrentYearValue] and hard coding a year instead to see if you get different results that way.

Comment: M-CY and relative measure are ok in the matrix. M-PY growth is also visible like postcard but not in the matrix correctly

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is here:

```
M-PY_Growth = calculate([M-PY_Sales]-[M-PY2_Sales];'Detail Sales Report')
```

Using calculate in this form has an implicit inclusion of the ALL() function around the filter term which will strip out the context of the rows the measure sits within.
To override this try:

```
M-PY_Growth = calculate([M-PY_Sales]-[M-PY2_Sales];KEEPFILTERS('Detail Sales Report'))
```

If that doesn't work you may need to experiment with ALLEXCEPT() to selectively keep district as a filter but allow the year context to be adjusted.